# Set a dynamic background colors based on themes in react native

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm attempting a theme type system, where i can create themes as json files, and then style my app based on it. For the most part all of it works except 2 parts for some reason,

1. Text Color
2. Background Colors

So everything else is styled correctly, but the backgroundColor and text colors just wont for some reason. I have checked multiple times over that the theme's values are available, console.log prints them fine too. There's no error message, and other styling from the theme works fine.

Here's where i load in the themes

```
const themes = {
    DEFAULT: require('./../assets/themes/default.json')
};

let theme = {};

function loadDefaultTheme() {
    parseTheme(themes.DEFAULT);
}

function parseTheme(json) {
    theme.name = json.name;
    theme.backgroundColor = json.backgroundColor;
    theme.navBackgroundColor = json.navBackgroundColor;
    theme.blueColor = json.blueColor;
    theme.redColor = json.redColor;
    theme.darkBlueColor = json.darkBlueColor;
    theme.placeholderColor = json.placeholderColor;
    theme.buttonTextColor = json.buttonTextColor;
    theme.textColor = json.textColor;
    theme.iconColor = json.iconColor;
    theme.iconActiveColor = json.iconActiveColor;
    theme.navTextColor = json.navTextColor;
    theme.navActiveTextColor = json.navActiveTextColor;
}

module.exports = {
    themes: themes,
    theme: theme,
    loadDefaultTheme: loadDefaultTheme,
    parseTheme: parseTheme
};
```

Here's my styling

```
const welcomeStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        flex: 1,
        width: Info.WINDOW_WIDTH,
        height: Info.WINDOW_HEIGHT
    },
    logo: {
        width: '50%',
        height: '50%',
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },
    text: {
        color: ThemeParser.theme.textColor,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
    },
    appNameText: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 30,
        marginTop: -60
    },
    descText: {
        fontSize: 22
    },
    loginView: {
        width: Info.WINDOW_WIDTH,
        height: Info.WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.6,
        backgroundColor: ThemeParser.theme.backgroundColor,
        borderTopColor: '#FE5656', borderTopWidth: 4,
        paddingTop: 25
    }
});
```

Finally, my theme:

```
{
  "name": "Default",
  "backgroundColor": "#1D1D1D",
  "navBackgroundColor": "#343434",
  "blueColor": "#05b7ed",
  "redColor": "#FF5757",
  "darkBlueColor": "#047A9E",
  "placeholderColor": "#545454",
  "buttonTextColor": "white",
  "textColor": "white",
  "iconColor": "#047A9E",
  "iconActiveColor": "#05B7ED",
  "navTextColor": "#C1C1C1",
  "navActiveTextColor": "white"
}
```

I have this bit elsewhere but this works for some reason...

```
<TouchableOpacity style={[global.globalStyles.halfButton, {backgroundColor: ThemeParser.theme.redColor}]} />
```

Edit: Components which the styles are not being applied. They work fine when i statically type a color like 'white' or '#1d1d1d'

```
<View style={styles.loginStyles.loginView}>
                        <Input
                            placeholder='Token'
                            placeholderTextColor={ThemeParser.theme.placeholderColor}
                            returnKeyType='done'
                            inputStyle={styles.loginStyles.token}
                            leftIcon={<Ionicons name='md-key' size={32} color={ThemeParser.theme.blueColor} />}
                            onChangeText={text => this.setState({token: text})}
                        />

                        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={[global.globalStyles.halfButton, {backgroundColor: ThemeParser.theme.blueColor, borderRightColor: 'black', borderRightWidth: 4}]} onPress={() => AniListAuth.getALCode()}>
                                    <Text style={global.globalStyles.buttonText}>Get Code</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>

                                <TouchableOpacity style={[global.globalStyles.halfButton, {backgroundColor: ThemeParser.theme.redColor}]} onPress={() => AniListAuth.login(this.state.token)}>
                                    <Text style={global.globalStyles.buttonText}>Sign In</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </View>
```

The background color for the TouchableOpacity seems to work fine, but not for the View background color or Text color

Edit2: Here's a snack of the project thus far if my code above isn't as clear... http://snack.expo.io/Hk1_2AOtr

Comment: Can you post the components on which styles are not applied?

Comment: @DragonBorn I've updated the post to include more information

Comment: It's a bit confusing where your stylesheets are coming from. You are using `styles.loginStyles.loginView` in your `View` component whereas in the above stylesheet I can see `welcomeStyles.loginView`. Can you make a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/)? It would be easier to debug.

Comment: Do you want `AniList Sign In` and `Skip Sign In` text to be in white color?

Comment: Yeah, it's the text color as well as  the background color of the sign in screen, it looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/7l4CfLU.png) when it should all look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/x5k8p89.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the working [snack](https://snack.expo.io/HyuMwEiFH).

**This is because you are exporting the theme object before you are parsing it.**

Your theme object is empty when you are exporting but you are parsing and adding properties to your object after it is exported which means you are calling `themeParser.loadDefaultTheme()` later in your code, by the time the empty theme object has already been exported.

It would be better if you use your themes object in your **ThemeParser.js** file:

```
const themes = {
    DEFAULT: require('./../assets/themes/default.json')
};

module.exports = {
    themes: themes,
    theme: theme,
    loadDefaultTheme: loadDefaultTheme,
    parseTheme: parseTheme
};
```

and use it in **GlobalStyles** like so:

```
buttonText: {
  color: ThemeParser.themes.DEFAULT.textColor,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: 20
}
```

And in **WelcomeStyles** like so:

```
text: {
    color: ThemeParser.themes.DEFAULT.textColor,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
},

loginView: {
    width: Info.WINDOW_WIDTH,
    height: Info.WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.6,
    backgroundColor: ThemeParser.themes.DEFAULT.backgroundColor,
    borderTopColor: '#FE5656', borderTopWidth: 4,
    paddingTop: 25
},
```

You can make the checks according to your needs when you want to load the `themes` object or `theme` object.